# HTML version for iPad Browser?

Tags: ipad

I need to develop a web application for iPad. I am not sure about the HTML version and JQuery Compatibility or JavaScript about iPad browser. Can anyone Help please?

Comment: See http://www.apple.com/safari/features.html

Answer (score 1):

Mobile Safari on iPads and iPhones [supports a subset of HTML5](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/HTMLTags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001262) and jQuery: there's a jQuery [plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/swipebin) to bind swipe events to the DOM.

Comment: basically, i have no idea for developing web apps for ipad. I need to develop web application using asp.net for iPad. So How i will need to handle swipe events. thanks for quick reply Stuart...